# How can I get text data from Handheld QR code scanner?

Tags: android, qr-code, barcode-scanner, android-hardware, android-usb

I am using honeywell barcode scanner(HF680). And I connected it to my Android Device(Desktop). I need to get the scanned data as text. It works like keyboard. So, It seems like I can't get the data internally like Camera Scanning.

How can I approach this?

I don't think Honeywell's supporting SDK nor Document. I can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the port you use. HF680 provides two different ports. If you use USB then, you can't use serial input. But it acts as keyboard. So, you can `onKeyDown` method.

```
    val barcode = StringBuilder("")

    override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        // TODO: add up the chars
        barcode.append(...)
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
    }
```

And generally, scanners provides some feature that indicates the end such as '\n' or Enter key or special characters. Otherwise, you can set a receiving time so that after a few milliseconds it wouldn't append the string.

Comment: Hi do you have any sample related to getting the barcode scanner output while waiting for a few milliseconds?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to use an `EditText`. The scanner input will go into it when it is focused. You can then read it from there.

Comment: Yes, I can get it but I want to manage the data internally(not visible). I can make the text and EditText white or invisible. However, I think it's not a good approach, I want it to work internally like QR scanner camera. Ex. as soon as it detects and decode the code then, it logs in automatically with the user data in QR code. I don't want the user to click a button after scan.

Comment: @c-an did you find any way?

Comment: @Sushant Somani yes sure.

Comment: can you share with me?

Comment: I added the answer. @SushantSomani

Comment: @c-an how are you getting these characters?

Answer (score 0):

Its good to use `dispatchKeyEvent` than `onKeyDown`.
Because, dispatchKeyEvent() will pass the event to onKeyListener if there is activity. This is when onKey() is called.

```
private var barcode = ""
override fun dispatchKeyEvent(event: android.view.KeyEvent): Boolean {
    
    val c = event.unicodeChar

    //accept 0-9, A-Z, a-z, " " and "enter"
    if (c in 48..57 || c in 65..90 || c in 97..122 || c == 10 || c == 32) {
      if(event.action == 0) {
        if (c in 48..57 || c in 65..90 || c in 97..122 || c == 32) {
          barcode += c.toChar()
        } else {
          if (barcode != "") {
            val bar = barcode
            barcode = ""
            Toast.makeText(this, "Barcode: $bar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            Log.i(TAG, "Barcode: $bar")
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return true
}
```